# url.replace with multiple replacements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've currently got the following to remove spaces and replace them with a hyphen.
How can I go about replacing a space with a hyphen and a dot with nothing and keep it in the same variable?

```
url = url.replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`url = url.replace(/\s/g, '-').replace(/\./g, '');` might do it.

Comment: For basic spaces and dots there is no need to use regex. Can just say url.replace(' ', '-').replace('.', '');

Comment: Good call. I didn't even think about that; just copied OPs code and appended. Thank you.

Comment: @ReneGeuze you will still need the `g` to hit all replaces.

Comment: So we'd need a regex pattern anyway.

Comment: Yeah  so as Jan answered thats correct and works.  How could I add replacing & with a '' to the that list.  Would it just be adding another .replace(/\&/g, '')

Comment: I don't think the ampersand needs to be escaped. So just /&/g within the first argument should suffice.

Comment: You guys are right, guess it's sunday ;) Forgot JavaScript string functions aren't so smart without regex.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
// This little gadget does replace for all not just first occurence like the native javascript function.
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(strTarget, strSubString){
  var strText = this;
  var intIndexOfMatch = strText.indexOf(strTarget);
  while (intIndexOfMatch != -1){
    strText = strText.replace(strTarget, strSubString);
    intIndexOfMatch = strText.indexOf(strTarget);
  }
  return(strText);
}
```